# PHP script run itself and it duplicates file handlers

Tags: php

I've got PHP script that collects some data. After couple seconds this script is calling itself using exec() command to collect data again. I really can't use CRON here for some reasons. The script looks something like this:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fh, 'Collecting data...');

// wait some time and run itself to collect data again
exec('(sleep 15 && php collect.php) > /dev/null 2>&1 &');

fwrite($fh, 'Data collected.');
fclose($fh);
```

It works as it should but there is one problem that I can't resolve for over two days of working...

As you can see, at the beggining of the script I setup the log writer using fopen() function. The problem is, when the script is planning to be run again using exec() function, opened log file is also opened in the next run of this script! It's strange to me, but it looks like exec() function is passing files handlers, but is it possible?

The problem is critial because after some time I can see in my server a lot of opened the same files by the one process:

[image]

Please help my if you can. I tried everything without effect :(

Comment: Can't you send the output to STDOUT?

Comment: I checked it twice and there is no output. Any errors. Nothing.

Comment: Why don't you just loop instead of calling the script again? Wrap your code in a while loop and at the end of the loop sleep for 15 seconds.

Comment: I mean instead of opening log.txt send the data to STDOUT and redirect STDOUT to log.txt

Comment: Close the file before `exec()`, reopen it when you need to write more data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling the script recursively (if the script you posted is the collect.php script) then you probably want to run the exec command after closing the filehandle like so:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fh, 'Collecting data...');
// do stuff
fwrite($fh, 'Data collected.');
fclose($fh);
// wait some time and run itself to collect data again
exec('(sleep 15 && php collect.php) > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but I need to save log "data collected" after I call the exec() function. I do some other stuff there and I unfortunately can't move exec() at the end of the script.

Comment: Do you have more information on why it's not an option in your use case?

Comment: Perhaps re-open the file handle after the exec call then. Your stream will still be active while a child process performs the same operation, which may lead to locking across processes

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this is the only solution at this moment.